# How to use Win10 IoT Core on Multiple Displays?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to find a way to have my Win10 IoT Core system display on a local screen via HDMI (this part is fine), as well as be accessible through remote access and be mirrored.

The idea is that it can be remote accessed and controlled from another computer. And if needed, the application can be mirrored purely for a view-only display.

Would any code offer me the ability to remote access and/or mirror my application over the network to other devices.

I have already tried the Win10 IoT Remote Client and I get the issue where it just displays a white screen but still allows my mouse and keyboard input to go through remotely. I am looking for an alternative way to do this.

Any insight to either of these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What device were you using, Raspberry Pi, DragonBoard or MinnowBoard or other device? And which build of Windows IoT Core were you testing the Remote Client? From release 16299, **Remote Client** does not support for Raspberry Pi. Please use a board with accelerated graphics such as Minnowboard Max or Dragonboard or attach a monitor for local display, and remote client works. Please refer to the known issue in the [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/commercial/fallcreatorsupdate#known-issues).

If you were not using Raspberry Pi, you can refer to the [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/remotedisplay#troubleshooting), here introduced how to troubleshoot the white screen issue when trying to connect.

Comment: Does IoT Core support multiple monitors at all?  I guess I was under the impression that multiple monitors are not supported.

Comment: I am using a SBC. https://www.rtd.com/PC104/CM/CMA34CR/CMA34CR.htm, this one to be specific. And I believe I was running W10IOTCore v17xxx. Does that mean this board doesn't have the required graphics capabilities to use Remote Client? Even with the 
Intel® HD Graphics 4000 embedded graphics?

Comment: @BWhelan, Windows IoT Core does not support multiple monitors. HD Graphics 4000 has the required capability to use Remote Client. But i'm not sure if the driver on Windows IoT Core can support this GPU.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Okay thank you, is this something that could be fixed in future updates of Remote Client? Or is it just not possible with this hardware?